# Pull to refresh listview crash

Tags: android, listview, admob, pull-to-refresh

I'm developing an android application which has a listview with two different view types

- Application item.
- Ad item (I'm using admob ad networks for these items).

The application works fine on 4.1+ android devices. but it crashes on 4.0.x devices.

The crash happens only in case of showing ads from the following networks:

- MobFox
- inMobi

I'm using chris banes pull to refresh (you can find it on):

- https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/

**I've tried many other adnetworks and it's working. Any Ideas?**

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:4312)
at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:4316)
at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:4316)
at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:4316)
at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:4316)
at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:4316)
at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:4316)
at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:4316)
at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:4316)
at android.view.ViewGroup.getChildVisibleRect(ViewGroup.java:4316)
at android.view.View.getGlobalVisibleRect(View.java:8126)
at android.webkit.WebView.calcOurVisibleRect(WebView.java:2952)
at android.webkit.WebView.calcOurContentVisibleRectF(WebView.java:2975)
at android.webkit.WebView.drawCoreAndCursorRing(WebView.java:4655)
at android.webkit.WebView.drawContent(WebView.java:4215)
at android.webkit.WebView.onDraw(WebView.java:4298)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11082)
at com.adsdk.sdk.banner.BannerAdView$1.draw(BannerAdView.java:185)
at android.view.View.buildDrawingCache(View.java:10799)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2845)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:462)
at android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.draw(GestureOverlayView.java:393)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2991)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.widget.ListView.drawChild(ListView.java:3219)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2099)
at android.widget.ListView.dispatchDraw(ListView.java:3214)
at com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView$InternalListView.d
ispatchDraw(PullToRefreshListView.java:293)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3419)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2991)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2991)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2094)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2991)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2991)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:462)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2991)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2989)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at net.simonvt.menudrawer.BuildLayerFrameLayout.dispatchDraw(BuildLayerFrameLayout.java:77)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:462)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2991)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer.dispatchDraw(MenuDrawer.java:667)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2991)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at net.simonvt.menudrawer.BuildLayerFrameLayout.dispatchDraw(BuildLayerFrameLayout.java:77)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:462)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2991)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at net.simonvt.menudrawer.MenuDrawer.dispatchDraw(MenuDrawer.java:667)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2991)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2593)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11085)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:462)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2145)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2026)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It's possible your layout is too complex, or it's recursively drawing.  How are you doing your layout?  Do you have a lot of nested LinearLayout/RelativeLayout/FrameLayout?  If so, try flattening your layout by eliminating some, especially in your list view cell.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend that you move your AdView outside of your ListView and display it on it's own either above or below. A ListView does not easily lend itself to display different types of objects, and consequently is the cause of many issues just like the one you have described.

By moving it out of the ListView your ListView code will radically simplify.

Comment: I concur with William. Apart from the reasons he has mentioned, if you put your ad view within your list view, when a user scrolls he won't be able to see the ad. Thus the ad will be served onto the phone but quite useless and your CTR will decrease.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i'm adding more than one ad to the listview and which might help me to increase the CTR.

Comment: If you are using Admob then displaying more than one ad on the same screen is against their policy. As I'm sure it is for the other networks. This is a sure way to get your account locked. In any case it would highly unlikely to increase your CTR, just increase the rage factor of your users.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem has happened when the ad view tries to load the Ad from these sources. And it happened in the [getChildVisibleRect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#getChildVisibleRect%28android.view.View,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Point%29) method in the Listview
I solved this problem by hacking this method to force it to return false, to return empty visible rectangle, for android versions lower than jellybean.

I've tested it and it's working fine for me.I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes in the `Manifest` file and it worked:

```
 android:largeHeap="true"
```

In the manifest file in the `<application>` tag

Comment: Are you sure you posted this in the right place? This seems to be identical to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20627700/implement-listview-and-youtubefailurerecoveryactivity-together-in-android-app/20628496#20628496) you posted to your own question.

Comment: There's no reason why that can even work. The crash isn't related to running out of memory. `android:largeHeap` is something to avoid at all times anyway.

Comment: @botteaap please refer [java.lang.StackOverflowError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html) Since my code was not recurrsive, I just increased the stack size and it worked, so I dont think its wrong.

Comment: @onkar in any case, you are just fighting the symptom, not solving the real problem. That is worked for you is nice, but not a general way to fix this.